# Have a function execute on the click of an 'input' button in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Javascript function document.write on the click of a button. Here's my code:

```
    function answer {
    var answer = eval(Calc.Input.value);

    if (BUTTON IS PRESSED);
    document.write(answer)
    }
```

The code for the button that is pressed is:

> ```
>   <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt"  VALUE="  =  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)">
> ```

So to sum up, on the click of that button, I need the answer of the value returned to become a variable, so that I can document.write it.

Comment: To make sure everything runs smoothly, you should use `eval()` waaay more.

Comment: I would recommend googling for a Javascript tutorial, any javascript tutorial, before asking a question here. I don't mean to come off as rude or anything, it's just that it doesn't look like you've spent any time reading about Javascript at all, and this isn't really the place to learn the absolute basics of a language. You run the risk of just getting lots of sarcastic comments a la adeneo's.

Comment: You can't `document.write` after the page has loaded.